# Build no is not reset to 1 while cloning the azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have cloned azure pipeline from another pipeline and specified the new git url to the cloned pipeline.
When I run the cloned pipeline, my build does not start from #1, instead the build number is taken from the last run and is incremented by 1

For eg: if I have a pipeline which is been build 100 time so its build no will be #100 and when I cloned this pipeline, the new pipeline will continue from #101.

P.S. I am using classic pipeline and not yaml pipeline.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just create a new pipeline and not reuse existing one with cloned repository.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Apologies for the delay. The solution worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> my build does not start from #1, instead the build number is taken from the last run and is incremented by 1

You can check if the Build number format is empty.

[image]

If this is empty, it will use the BuildID as the Build number, so when you clone the Pipeline, it is still incremented by 1 based on the latest Build Run id.

I suggest that you can define the Build number format: `$(rev:r)`

For example:

[image]

When you clone the pipeline, it will reset the count to #1.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kevin,
Apologies for the delay.
The solution worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes Kevin, I do want to. But I do not have enough reputation. Sorry